# How are beef cuts labeled in Russian?

Tags: beef, cut-of-meat, russian-cuisine

I looked up [cut of beef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_of_beef) on Wikipedia. There are no Russian names for cuts. I'm wondering what they're all called in Russian.

Comment: Hello George Chen! Even if we had a way of measuring this, it does not cover the criteria of being based on a concrete problem a professional or hobby cook is likely to face in the kitchen, and as such it is off topic.

Comment: I think OP's actual question, based on the article he links, is how primal cuts are defined in russian culture, rather than what is the most popular. A google image search found [this image](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2804/4341911482_fbd63b9e32_m.jpg), with no source and all labels in russian.

Comment: @GeorgeChen For a more up to date image, http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0 's first section, with the image not present on English wikipedia, is titled "Russia and the former Soviet Union", though the image it uses seems to be originally from the German wikipedia. The section near the bottom of the page is a diagram from an old public-domain Russian dictionary.

Comment: George, given that you're apparently satisfied with answers about what the cuts are called (not what's popular), I've edited your question and reopened it. (I'm also cleaning up all the tangential comments.) @Random832 we'd much appreciate you turning those things into an answer!

Comment: @GeorgeChen I added another link to my answer after you accepted it that you may find helpful.

Comment: @Jefromi I know that answers only consisting of links are frowned upon, but I have doubts about how much of the copyrighted material at the sources is appropriate to include in an answer to a general reference question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Russian Wikipedia article on Beef](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) has several diagrams - a current one in the main section apparently originally derived from the German wikipedia, and two others from older Russian sources.

I was also able to find [another site](http://zernograd.com/govyadina-i-telyatina/) with another diagram, and translations of some of the cuts into English, which is helpful because the names are difficult to translate to similar English cuts via Google Translate, which simply gives anatomical terms for many of them.

[Here is an article from the Moscow Times](http://www.themoscowtimes.com/opinion/article/getting-to-the-meat-of-the-matter/487693.html) discussing the subject, largely from the perspective of someone who only knows the American name for the cut they are looking for.